Chrome saving passwords with two websites but one similar login-name
I would like to store two websites names with a unique login-name using the password manager:

https://admin.hostpoint.ch/customer/Auth/Webmail
https://admin.hostpoint.ch/customer/Auth/Login

Chrome only saves https://admin.hostpoint.ch in both cases. So it denies to manually add a second password with the same name.
Is there a workaround known?

Chrome password manager is quite basic and supports only domain matching. Use a 3rd party password manager that has more features.
For example Bitwarden. I has advanced URI matching and supports all different parts of URLs - protocol, domain, port, path and parameters. Which works with autofill and its other features.
All you have to do is input your exact URLs:

https://admin.hostpoint.ch/customer/Auth/Webmail
https://admin.hostpoint.ch/customer/Auth/Login

as separate entries with separate passwords:

and that's it.
